# DirectX: Misaligned texture

Tags: directx-11, texture2d

I am attempting to load an obj model and apply a texture to it. I am currently using D3d11 only. The model is being exported from blender.

As it appears, I am able to successfully render the model's vertices and normals, however the texture coordinates appear to misaligned. The model successfully renders in other obj viewers so it must be my settings/code.

The only reason I can think of why this is happening is that CreateWICTextureFromFile is resizing the texture file causing the U,V coordinates to be misaligned.

[image: loaded obj model]

I load the model with the following (I convert it from left hand to right hand coordinates):

```
void Model::init_from_obj(char *filename){
    std::vector<Vector2> vertex_texture;
    std::vector<Vector3> vertex_normal;

    float x, y, z;
    int a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h, i;
    std::string line;
    std::ifstream obj_file(filename);

    while (getline(obj_file, line)){
        if (line[0] == 'v' && line[1] == ' '){
            sscanf_s(&line[0], "v %f %f %f", &x, &y, &z);
            this->verts.push_back({ x, y, z  * -1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f });
        }
        else if (line[0] == 'v' && line[1] == 't'){
            sscanf_s(&line[0], "vt %f %f", &x, &y);
            vertex_texture.push_back({ x, 1.0f - y });
        }
        else if (line[0] == 'v' && line[1] == 'n'){
            sscanf_s(&line[0], "v %f %f %f", &x, &y, &z);
            vertex_normal.push_back({ x, y, z * -1.0f});
        }
        else if (line[0] == 'f'){
            sscanf_s(&line[0], "f %d/%d/%d %d/%d/%d %d/%d/%d", &a, &d, &g, &b, &e, &h, &c, &f, &i);
            this->indices.push_back((a-1));

            this->verts[(a - 1)].tU = vertex_texture[(d - 1)].x;
            this->verts[(a - 1)].tV = vertex_texture[(d - 1)].y;

            this->verts[(a - 1)].nX = vertex_normal[(g - 1)].x;
            this->verts[(a - 1)].nY = vertex_normal[(g - 1)].y;
            this->verts[(a - 1)].nZ = vertex_normal[(g - 1)].z;

            this->indices.push_back((c - 1));

            this->verts[(c - 1)].tU = vertex_texture[(f - 1)].x;
            this->verts[(c - 1)].tV = vertex_texture[(f - 1)].y;

            this->verts[(c - 1)].nX = vertex_normal[(i - 1)].x;
            this->verts[(c - 1)].nY = vertex_normal[(i - 1)].y;
            this->verts[(c - 1)].nZ = vertex_normal[(i - 1)].z;

            this->indices.push_back((b - 1));

            this->verts[(b - 1)].tU = vertex_texture[(e - 1)].x;
            this->verts[(b - 1)].tV = vertex_texture[(e - 1)].y;

            this->verts[(b - 1)].nX = vertex_normal[(h - 1)].x;
            this->verts[(b - 1)].nY = vertex_normal[(h - 1)].y;
            this->verts[(b - 1)].nZ = vertex_normal[(h - 1)].z;
        }
    }
}
```

I load the texture with the follow:

```
hr = DirectX::CreateWICTextureFromFile(directx.dev, this->texture_filename, nullptr, &texture);

if (FAILED(hr))
    debug_file << "FAILED to load model texture" << std::endl;

// Describe the Sample State
D3D11_SAMPLER_DESC sampDesc;
ZeroMemory(&sampDesc, sizeof(sampDesc));
sampDesc.Filter = D3D11_FILTER_MIN_MAG_MIP_LINEAR;
sampDesc.AddressU = D3D11_TEXTURE_ADDRESS_WRAP;
sampDesc.AddressV = D3D11_TEXTURE_ADDRESS_WRAP;
sampDesc.AddressW = D3D11_TEXTURE_ADDRESS_WRAP;
sampDesc.ComparisonFunc = D3D11_COMPARISON_NEVER;
sampDesc.MinLOD = 0;
sampDesc.MaxLOD = D3D11_FLOAT32_MAX;

//Create the Sample State
hr = directx.dev->CreateSamplerState(&sampDesc, &SamplerState);
```

Lastly, I render it with these settings:

```
directx.devcon->PSSetShaderResources(0, 1, &texture);
directx.devcon->PSSetSamplers(0, 1, &SamplerState);
```

If there is anything else I need to provide, please tell me. It been about 3 days and I have no clue.

Comment: Resizing the texture should have no effect on the way that it's displayed on the model, as the texture will be mapped to UV coordinates between 0 and 1. The only thing I can think of is that your texture coordinates are being read incorrectly. I recall a similar issue with my own code loading .obj files incorrectly; the seams of the model were always a bit screwy. Unfortunately I was never able to solve it.

Comment: I found that if I attempt to manually map a texture, it is also slightly off. Thats why I believe it is something with directx or the texture loader.

Comment: Looking through the WICTextureLoader file, I found that there is scaling if the size of the texture exceeds the maximum UV dimensions the device supports (given by `D3Dxx_REQ_TEXTURE2D_U_OR_V_DIMENSION`). Since the question is tagged as DirectX 11, I'm going to assume you're using feature level 11.0, where this is defined to 16384 pixels. It's a long shot, but check the dimensions of the texture. Other than that, there's only one other thing I can think of: a bug in the shader. Simplest way to test that is to make a cube (a "Companion Cube") and see if that shows the same problems.